# Gitlab CI/CD pipeline skips a job

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci

so for school we need to set up a terraform environment trough a CI/CD gitlab pipeline.

For some reason not al my stages start.

Gitlab-ci.yml code below:

```
include:
  - template: Terraform/Base.gitlab-ci.yml  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Terraform/Base.gitlab-ci.yml




stages:
  - Build and Push
  - validate
  - build
  - deploy
  - cleanup


Build and Push:  # Corrected stage name
  stage: Build and Push  # Corrected stage name
  image: docker:25.0.4
  services:
    - docker:25.0.4-dind
  script:
    - apk add python3
    - apk add py3-pip
    - python3 -m venv venv
    - source venv/bin/activate
    - pip3 install awscli
    - aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <accountid>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    - docker build -t le-repo application/crudapp/.
    - docker tag le-repo:latest <accountid>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/le-repo:latest
    - docker push <accountid>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/le-repo:latest

validate:
  extends: .terraform:validate
  needs: []
  

build:
  extends: .terraform:build
  environment:
    name: $TF_STATE_NAME
    action: prepare
  

deploy:
  extends: .terraform:deploy
  dependencies:
    - build
  environment:
    name: $TF_STATE_NAME
    action: start
  `
```

And as you can see he doesnt add the "deploy" stage

[image]

Thanks for the help

Tried adding "destroy" job after the "deploy" job and this works.
Also tried changing the deploy code to the following: deploy:

```
extends: .terraform:deploy
  dependencies:
    - build
  environment:
    name: $TF_STATE_NAME
    action: start
  when: always
```

This also doesnt start it.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see by yourself in the source link you provided, the `.terraform:deploy` job has rules preventing it to run.

```yaml
terraform:deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - gitlab-terraform apply
  resource_group: ${TF_STATE_NAME}
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $TF_AUTO_DEPLOY == "true"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual
```

It will run only for commit on the default branch and then either require manual trigger or automatically depending if `TF_AUTO_DEPLOY` is set.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, completely overlooked that.